# dual boot mac and existing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, macosx

I know this problem's thread are available but mine is different.
I have two HDD installed. I have already installed ubuntu in /dev/sda1 and running fine. Now i install iMac in /dev/sba1 and that also running fine.

Problem is when i need to run mac then i need to select mac hdd as first boot from bios and same when need to boot on ubuntu.

I tried to add mac in grub (from ubuntu) but it did not work(latter i find the information that mac does not use MBR technique). Now i am trying to boot ubuntu from mac HDD.

From existing solution in internet they asked to create an empty partition and install ubuntu there. But i can do this. I have already installed ubuntu.

How to solve this problem? I need help. Thanks in advance.

Note: I have installed refit in mac. But does not show anything at start up.

My HDD partition table: [Information from mac terminal]

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *74.5 Gi    disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS MAC                     18.3 Gi    disk0s1
   2:               Windows_NTFS MOVIES                  28.3 Gi    disk0s2
   3:               Windows_NTFS ANY                     27.9 Gi    disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *232.9 Gi   disk1
   1:                      Linux                         10.5 Gi    disk1s3
   2:               Windows_NTFS Windows7                19.5 Gi    disk1s1
   3:               Windows_NTFS EXTRA                   62.0 Gi    disk1s5
   4:               Windows_NTFS ENTERTAIN               62.0 Gi    disk1s6
   5:               Windows_NTFS SOFT&GAME               62.0 Gi    disk1s7
   6:               Windows_NTFS EDUCATION               16.9 Gi    disk1s8
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *20.0 Mi    disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         31.5 Ki    disk2s1
   2

:                  Apple_HFS rEFIt                   20.0 Mi    disk2s2
```

I am not sure what is /dev/disk2. First two disk(disk0 and disk1) are real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `iBoot` from tonymacx86.com. It is built on the Chameleon (or more recently [Chimera](http://tonymacx86.blogspot.com/2011/04/chimera-unified-chameleon-bootloader.html)) bootloader. It performs the same task as grub, but it is designed to work with OSX. It is also `UEFI` capable if your motherboard supports it.

Register at this forum: http://www.tonymacx86.com/
Then download this installer in OSX: http://www.tonymacx86.com/C:Dq-OCPpT/Chimera-1.7.0.zip

Comment: i did. But it slow down the mac, hang mouse and keyboard and no boot

Comment: There's no way that Chameleon by itself would slow down the mac, as it is a bootloader. However  OSX is funny about how it loads kernel drivers. What you should do is determine which kext OSX needs to boot and put them in /Extra so that Chameleon will load them at boot.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to run the MultiBeast utility. Use this link for Lion: http://www.tonymacx86.com/C:Dq-OCPpT/MultiBeast-4.2.1.zip and this link for everything else: http://www.tonymacx86.com/C:Dq-OCPpT/MultiBeast-3.10.1.zip Read through this thread to see good basic MultiBeast setups: http://www.tonymacx86.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10172